# Easiest way to add row border when there are rowspans present?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a `table`, half of whose cells are `rowspan="2"` and the other half are not. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vyAX/1/).

I want a border between each "actual" row. That means for H1 and H2, it needs to be on every row. But for H3 and H4, it needs to be on every other row.

What's the most elegant way to do this using CSS? I'd prefer not to have to put a classname on every `td` just to get this working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just [separate your headers from the actual rows](http://jsfiddle.net/4vyAX/2/) using `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. then style only the `<tbody>` rows. of course you can still style the headers, but it's good mark-up to separate the table header from the content.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>  
            <th>H2</th> 
            <th>H3</th> 
            <th>H4</th>  
        </tr>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">1</td>
          <td rowspan="2">2</td>
          <td>3a</td>
          <td>4a</td>
        </tr>
        ...

/* Style in question: */
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #BBB;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, my actual code uses thead and tbody. In fact there is some difference between the fiddle and my actual code becuase I'm getting different results. I'll come back to this later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your own fiddle, simply [change](http://jsfiddle.net/4vyAX/3/) the `(even)` selector to `(odd)`. The resulting border at the bottom is not uniform due to different border widths on the table and the cells, but that's also simple to correct.

Comment: Hmm, the styles are there (I see them on the rows in the console) but I'm not seeing a border. If I use `odd`, I only see a border on the rows on the right side. It's like the rows with `rowspan="2"` aren't getting a border no matter what I do. (This is in my real code, not the fiddle. As far as I can tell they are the same but I will keep looking).

Comment: I think this has something to do with `border-collapse`. When I set it to `collapse`, the row borders appear but a good portion of the table's right border disappears. I added another style to manually place a right border on the last td in each row and now it looks fine. I have no idea wtf was going on, but anyway, it works now in a really convoluted way.